# The total $p$-variation of a standard Brownian motion is infinite almost surely for any $p > 1/2$

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, total-variation

How can I show that the $p$-variation of a standard Brownian motion is infinite almost surely for any $p > 1/2$. By this I mean the total variation,

$lim_{\delta\to0} (sup_{\pi:\delta(\pi)=\delta} \sum_{j=1}^{N(\pi)}$$|B(t_j)-B(t_{j-1})|^p)$,

where $\delta(\pi)$ is the mesh of the partition $\pi$.

Comment: Any thoughts on the problem? Perhaps you might want to take a look at the literature (that is, a book on Brownian motion)?

Comment: It is tricky to find reading that deals with total variation as opposed to just variation (ie not taking the sup), especially in cases p>1. I can solve the case p=1, and I suppose from that the case p<1 follows fairly easily. I could probably do 1<p<2 in a similar fashion to the standard proof for p=1, however the case p>2 is the real problem.

Comment: It may be possible to do by: For each M, find an upper bound (for each delta) for the probability that the finite variation of a partition of mesh delta exceeds M. Then use a Borel Cantelli argument to show that this doesn't happen infinitely often. This seems fairly long though, I am hoping for a neater way.